# Gradient shape blending position in LinearLayout

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a requirement of achieving following type of gradient on my LinearLayout

[image]

Can someone help me to achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <gradient
        android:startColor="#ffffff"  
        android:centerColor="#ffffff"        
        android:endColor="#ff0000"
        android:angle="270"
     />        
</shape>
```

Answer (score 0):

defining in xml file you can get like this way

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <gradient
        android:startColor="#ffffffff"         
        android:endColor="#ffff0000"
        android:angle="270"
     />
     <corners android:radius="1dp"/>
</shape>
```

save this in mygradientbg.xml into drawable folder

in you linearlayout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/gradient"
    >
</LinearLayout>
```

but it will stretch with the width and height

Comment: It won't control the blending position as I want. I want very thin red gradient